# Different element is receiving the click, even though Xpath is correct and unique(Protractor)

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium, protractor, ui-automation

I have two elements like below

**Property Element**
[image: Property]

Xpath->  `//sprk-accordion-item[@ng-reflect-title="Property"]//sprk-icon`

**Repair Element**
[image: Repair]

Xpath->  `//sprk-accordion-item[@ng-reflect-title="Repair"]//sprk-icon`

The code I am using to click the element

```
public async click(webElement: ElementFinder) {
    try {
        this.expectConditions.waitForElementToBeVisible(webElement);
        this.moveToElement(webElement);
        await webElement.click();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error while clicking the element' + webElement.locator().toString() + 'Error:: ' + error);
    }
}

    public async waitForElementToBeVisible(element: ElementFinder) {
    const ec = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
   await browser.wait(ec.visibilityOf(element), this.time, 'Unable to find the element' + element.locator().toString());
   }


public async moveToElement(webElement: ElementFinder) {
    await browser.actions().
        mouseMove(webElement).
        perform();
}


click(element(by.xpath('//sprk-accordion-item[@ng-reflect-title="Property"]//sprk-icon'));
```

My problem here is let's say if I am running the test for like 10 times

- 4 times tests are running as expected. when I am trying to click the
  property element, property element is receiving the click.

  4 times tests are running not as expected. when I am trying to click
  the property element, Repair element is receiving the click, even
  though I didn't even write any code to click the repair element.

  2 times no element is receiving the click.

There is no focus issue because in the click code I am moving to the element before clicking it. The x-paths I am using are unique and they are not even dynamic.

when I am placing `browser.sleep(1000);` before clicking the property element, then it is clicking as expected. Still, if it is the timing issue, it should say the element is not found. But how come it's clicking the Repair element when locators are unique??

Hopefully, someone answers this question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting any error messages when the click goes to the wrong element? Specifically about the element not being able to receive the click?

Comment: No, I am not receiving any error message, it's just clicking the next element which is not written in the test.
I also wrote a console log to check the locator, the log is writing back the locator which is not getting clicked.

Comment: Could you provide more information / code for `expectConditions.waitForElementToBeVisible` and `moveToElement`? It will provide more information about what Protractor APIs you are calling to cause this issue.

Comment: I updated the question which I am using for `waitForElementToBeVisible` and `moveToElement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss several `await`:

```
public async click(webElement: ElementFinder) {
    try {
        await this.expectConditions.waitForElementToBeVisible(webElement);
        await this.moveToElement(webElement);
        await webElement.click();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error while clicking the element' + webElement.locator().toString() + 'Error:: ' + error);
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the question which I am using for `waitForElementToBeVisible` and `moveToElement` those functions have await. so I am not using await in the click method where I am calling them.

Comment: all `async` functions return `Promise<something>`, so when you use them you Must write `await` before